# What would happen to a body in an astronaut suit over time if floating free?

Tags: biochemistry, decay

I'm not sure if this is best in Biology or Physics, but on Earth we decay to skeletons and then eventually to dust.  What would happen in space in a space suit?

Comment: You are probably going to need to be more specific.  If the body is floating free for an extended period of time then it must be either in orbit around something or really far away from any gravity well.  If it's in sunlight, it will get really hot, if it's not it will get really cold.  How long will the suit stay pressurized? How much oxygen is available until then?  I'm not an expert on this site, but I doubt you'll get anything decent with this question as it stands.

Comment: @AdamPhelps. I agree. It heavily depends on *where*, as close to the sun the answer is very different than in a cold environment far from any heat source. Also the *how* matters, as the space suit characteristics also matters in terms of heat and radiation that may affect the body

Comment: Closed Duplicate. Answer here : http://biology.stackexchange.com/a/20958/8804

Comment: That's not a duplicate, though it is very close.  To answer your question Adam, by "floating free" I mean you are ejected from a spaceship between galaxies.  You're lightyears from anything.  Would a suit stay pressurized for 100 years?  Would the oxygen run out?  I don't know, that's part of the question.

Comment: @Raoul the moon has little atmosphere and gravity which is not the same as space

Comment: @CRags, thanks for that, but I think given the answers to those questions, the more important part is that it is very close to a sun, which apparently makes a huge difference.